# Handling null values in protobuffers

Tags: java, null, protocol-buffers

I am working on something which fetches data from database and constructs protobuff message. Given the possibility that null values can be fetched from the database for certain fields , I will get Null-pointer exception while trying to construct the protobuff message. Getting to know that null is not supported in protobuffs from the thread http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=57, I am wondering whether the only other way to handle NPE getting thrown is to insert manual checks into the java file corresponding to the proto like below!

```
message ProtoPerson{
    optional string firstName = 1;
    optional string lastName = 2;
    optional string address1 = 3;
}

ProtoPerson.Builder builder = ProtoPerson.Builder.newBuilder();
if (p.getFirstName() != null) builder.setFirstName(p.getFirstName());
if (p.getLastName() != null) builder.setLastName(p.getLastName());
if (p.getAddress1() != null) builder.setAddress1(p.getAddress1());
...
```

So can someone please clarify whether there is any other possible efficient way to handle the null values during protobuff construction??

Comment: Shorter version of the same thing: `Optional.ofNullable(p.getFirstName()).ifPresent(builder::setFirstName);`

Comment: is the thread you linked the good one? I can't find anything related to null values there. Maybe these are more related https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/1606 & https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5450

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no easy solution to this.  I'd recommend just dealing with the null checks.  But if you really want to get rid of them, here are a couple ideas:

- You could write a [code generator plugin](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.compiler.plugin.pb) which adds `setOrClearFoo()` methods to each Java class.  The Java code generator provides [insertion points](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#plugins) for this (see the end of that page).
- You could use Java reflection to iterate over the `get*()` methods of `p`, call each one, check for `null`, and then call the `set*()` method of `builder` if non-null.  This will have the added advantage that you won't have to update your copy code every time you add a new field, but it will be much slower than writing code that copies each field explicitly.

Comment: Please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474024/how-to-accomplish-inheritance-using-proto-buffers

Comment: Has anyone actually created a code generator plugin that does the setOrClearFoo() or provide an example?

Comment: I have tried reflection but the performance takes a steep dive as the proto becomes big and you need to map a large dataset to the proto objects.

Answer (score 88):

Disclaimer: Answer from a Googler using protobufs on a daily basis. I'm by no means representing Google in any way.

1. Name your proto `Person` instead of `PersonProto` or `ProtoPerson`. Compiled protobufs are just class definitions specified by the language you are using, with some improvements. Adding "Proto" is extra verbosity.
2. Use `YourMessage.hasYourField()` instead of `YourMessage.getYourField() != null`. Default value for protobuf string is an empty string, which does **NOT** equal to null. Whereas, no matter whether your field is unset or cleared or empty string, `.hasYourField()` always returns false. See [default values for common protobuf field types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#optional).
3. You've probably known, but I wanna say explicitly: **Don't programmatically set a protobuf field to `null`.** Even for outside of protobuf, `null` [causes all sorts of problems](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained). Use `.clearYourField()` instead.
4. `Person.Builder` class does **NOT** have a `.newBuilder()` method. `Person` class does. Understand the *Builder Pattern* like this: You create a new builder only if you do not have it yet.

A rewrite of your protobuf:

```
message Person {
  optional string first_name = 1;
  optional string last_name = 2;
  optional string address_1 = 3;
}
```

A rewrite of your logic:

```
Person thatPerson = Person.newBuilder()
    .setFirstName("Aaa")
    .setLastName("Bbb")
    .setAddress1("Ccc")
    .build();

Person.Builder thisPersonBuilder = Person.newBuilder()

if (thatPerson.hasFirstName()) {
  thisPersonBuilder.setFirstName(thatPerson.getFirstName());
}

if (thatPerson.hasLastName()) {
  thisPersonBuilder.setLastName(thatPerson.getLastName());
}

if (thatPerson.hasAddress1()) {
  thisPersonBuilder.setAddress1(thatPerson.getAddress1());
}

Person thisPerson = thisPersonBuilder.build();
```

And if `thatPerson` is a person object that you created that has attribute values that could be an empty string, empty spaces or null, then I'd recommend using [Guava's `Strings` library](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html):

```
import static com.google.common.base.Strings.nullToEmpty;

Person.Builder thisPersonBuilder = Person.newBuilder()

if (!nullToEmpty(thatPerson.getFirstName()).trim().isEmpty()) {
  thisPersonBuilder.setFirstName(thatPerson.getFirstName());
}

if (!nullToEmpty(thatPerson.hasLastName()).trim().isEmpty()) {
  thisPersonBuilder.setLastName(thatPerson.getLastName());
}

if (!nullToEmpty(thatPerson.hasAddress1()).trim().isEmpty()) {
  thisPersonBuilder.setAddress1(thatPerson.getAddress1());
}

Person thisPerson = thisPersonBuilder.build();
```

Comment: Your post may be full of good advice...but I'm not sure you understood his question?  For instance, his data isn't coming from another protobuf object; it's coming from a database or some other source, and may have nulls.  He wanted to know how to easily deal with the nulls, basically.

Comment: Good point Erhannis, thanks.  I updated the answer by adding a section to deal with non-protocol-buffer objects that has empty string values, consecutive-space values, and null values.

Comment: 'causes all sorts of problems' link is dead, and I'd really like to learn more

Comment: @kinbiko:  Fixed the link.  Guava has been migrated from Google Code to GitHub, thus the new link now.  Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: I will name my proto as PersonMessage, to distinguish between my Person class (represent a person) and PersonMessage class (represent message about person). I see nothing wrong with his naming PersonProto, or ProtoPerson. Maybe this is just my personal opinion.

Comment: How should be dealed with NULL values using proto3? There are no "YourMessage.hasYourField()" Methods...

Comment: Isn't this answer just the same as what's suggested in the question - just use null checks? The relevant part - the part that answers the question is only in the last paragraph. Confusingly the other part of the answer is answering questions that haven't been asked.

Comment: Regarding 1) the reason people tend to have classes named to indicate it's a protobuf object is that for most cases the entity you're transferring is already an existing domain object. Using the same named class for the proto class as the domain object might make sense but becomes very confusing when you have both of these classes being reference in another class. I generally wouldn't prepend proto though but instead append DTO to indicate its purpose better: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: IDK this seems like a bug to me, the Protobuf generated code at first glance looks like it supports the fluent builder pattern, as this question illustrates it clearly does not.

Comment: I using pb in my C++ program. I have a pb object which has a repeated string field. with a very rarely probability, the last string, will be changed to null. Then my program will be core. Do you have any idea about the issue? I am sure the pb object not in critical section.

Comment: The problem calling the proto type Person instead of ProtoPerson, is you will already have an API or Domain or DB object called Person that you are mapping from.  So if you don't give the protobuf object a unique name then you have to use fully qualified types in your code.

Comment: This answer is specific to protobuf 2: protobuf `optional` as well as methods like `hasFirstName` on scalar are not available in proto3.

Comment: flawless tips @MichaelXinSun

Answer (score 52):

## Proto 3

wrappers.proto supports nullable values:

- string(StringValue),
- int(Int32Value),
- bool(BoolValue)
- and etc

Example

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message ProtoPerson {
    google.protobuf.StringValue firstName = 1;
    google.protobuf.StringValue lastName = 2;
    google.protobuf.StringValue address1 = 3;
    google.protobuf.Int32Value age = 4;
}
```

Comment: Is there a similar way for non basic types?

Comment: @muslidrikk Non basic types are nullable by default

Comment: Full list here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/protobuf-data-types#nullable-types

Comment: So, how to set a null value? I looked into generated sources, `StringValue.newBuilder().setValue(value).build()` also has a null check in `.setValue(..)` method

Comment: Answering my question from the comment above ^: `StringValue` could be "not set". On the recipient's side, `StringValue` would have `.has*` methods(like `.hasUserId()`) which could be used *instead* of a null check. In that way you can avoid passing some primitive values. But don't try to set `null` into `StringValue` field. It is so called "has pattern".