# Upcasting the downcasted object back in protobuffers

Tags: upcasting, protocol-buffers

Below is the proto code,

```
message Animal {
    optional string name = 1;
    optional int32 age = 2;  
}    

message Dog{
    optional string breed = 1;
}
```

Then the  sample class using the above proto

```
public class InheritanceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Dog dog = Dog.getDefaultInstance();
        printAnimalName(dog.getAnimal());
    }

    public static void printAnimal(Animal animal){
        Dog dog = (Dog)animal; // Not at all possible right!
    }

}
```

Is up-casting possible only by having an instance of dog as "required" in animal? or Is there any other way of upcasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to be clear:  "Upcasting" means casting a `Dog` to an `Animal`.  "Downcasting" means casting an `Animal` to a `Dog`.  Your question is about how to upcast, but your example appears to be about downcasting.  I'll try to answer both.

In [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21474808/2686899), I presented three options for emulating inheritance with protobufs.

Option 1 makes upcasting easy but does not allow for downcasting.

Options 2 and 3 make downcasting possible, but do not support upcasting.

If you need to be able to both upcast and downcast, then you need to use option 2 or 3, but always pass around an `Animal` as simply an `Animal`.  That is, if you have a function which *only* works on `Dog`, but needs to access some of the members of `Animal` as well, it must take `Animal` as its argument.  The function's documentation should state that even though the argument type is `Animal`, the argument must have the `dog` field (or extension) set, i.e. it must actually be a `Dog`.  You should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` otherwise.

Editorial:  I know this is not a very satisfying answer.  Protocol Buffers does not implement true inheritance because we couldn't come up with any design that seemed reasonable.  The requirements of backwards- and forwards-compatibility on the wire make this problem a lot more complicated than it may seem.  In practice, though, we've found that inheritance is rarely actually what you want anyway, and one of the options I presented usually works fine.  In my opinion, inheritance makes sense for interfaces (i.e. collections of *methods* with *behavior*), but not for messages (i.e. collections of fields containing simple data).

Comment: I jus thought upcast and downcast mean the other way, thanks for clarifying!.. thn getting to know ab these inadequecies/complications in casting when i use inheritance in protos, I have decided not to bring these kind of relations among proto messages and keep it to the java wrappers which wrap the protos!

Comment: Then I have a doubt regarding updating a repeated field of a message type in a super message type. Is it possible to edit an added repeated field of a message type? I looked into the java source code generated from proto and found that a repeated field is built before getting added and so it's not possible. Is it possible by any chance?

Comment: If you have a repeated field `foo`, you can call `getFooBuilder()` or `addFooBuilder()` to get a `Builder` for an element, which you can then modify.  However, if you call `addFoo(someBuilder)`, and then you modify `someBuilder` after the call, those changes won't affect the added value.  (You can of course call `getFooBuilder(getFooCount() - 1)` to get a `Builder` for the element you just added, which you can then use to modify it.)

Comment: addFooBuilder() does the job for me thank you. Please answer this final question on the performance of builder as general data object,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586250/performance-analysis-of-using-protobuff-builders-as-general-data-object