# How to make null must error if input is empty in mybatis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc, mybatis, ibatis

Im trying to insert empty data and it must error but its still saving.
I try try/cath and if statement if null and still not working.
Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Output in this image [RPCbloom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDL5S.png)

This project is Spring-boot with GRPC and MyBatis.

```
package com.cartservice.Repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Delete;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Insert;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Options;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Result;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Results;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Update;

import com.cartservice.Model.Client;
import com.cartservice.Model.ProductEntity;
import com.grpcserver.product.ProductServer.Product;

@Mapper
public interface ProductDAO {
    
    
    @Insert("INSERT INTO tb_product(purchase_item,  productname, productbrand,productprice,productdescription,productquantity,productexpirationdate) " +
              " VALUES (#{purchase_item}, #{productname}, #{productbrand}, #{productprice}, #{productdescription}, #{productquantity}, #{productexpirationdate} )")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyColumn = "purchase_item", keyProperty = "purchase_item")
    public int insert(ProductEntity  productEntity);
    
    
    
     
}
```

```
    @Override
    public void insert(Product request, StreamObserver<APIResponse> responseObserver) {

    
    ProductEntity productEntity = new ProductEntity();

    
    productEntity.setPurchase_item(request.getPurchaseItem());
    productEntity.setProductname(request.getProductname());
    productEntity.setProductbrand(request.getProductbrand());
    productEntity.setProductprice(request.getProductprice());
    productEntity.setProductdescription(request.getProductdescription());
    productEntity.setProductquantity(request.getProductquantity());
    productEntity.setProductexpirationdate(dateConvert.getDateFromDateProto(request.getProductexpirationdate()));


    productServiceImpl.saveDataFromDTO(productEntity);
    APIResponse.Builder  responce = APIResponse.newBuilder();
    responce.setResponseCode(0).setResponsemessage("Succefull added to database " +productEntity);
    
    responseObserver.onNext(responce.build());
    responseObserver.onCompleted(); 
        
    
    
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

fix i use GRPC "hasField"

for more [Handling null values in protobuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227924/handling-null-values-in-protobuffers)