# Is it possible to return null value with gRPC protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, grpc, protobuf-net

I am using gRPC protobuf-net to facilitate communication between a client application and a service.

The client can send a command to retrieve an entity by its ID. On the server side, the service method calls a method in the repository which may return a null value if the entity does not exist.

The issue I’m encountering is that I receive an exception when the entity is null, but everything works fine when the entity is not null.

Therefore, I suspect that the problem lies in protobuf-net’s inability to serialize a null value.

One solution I’ve considered is to use a ‘Response’ class that has a property of the type of value to be sent, which can be null. This approach works, but I would prefer to avoid this solution if possible.

Does protobuf-net support the transmission of null values, or should I encapsulate the result in a ‘Response’ class?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

This is the code of the Iterface, the service implementation and the client implementation.

```
//Used as request because if I am not wrong, protobuf-net can't serialize a .NET primitve, I need a class.
[DataContract]
public class LongDTO
{
    public LongDTO() { }

    public LongDTO(long paramLong)
    {
        Long = paramLong;
    }



    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public readonly long Long;
}



[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    public Task<MyType?> GetEntityAsync(LongDTO paramLongRequest);
}




[Authorize]
public class MyServiceProtobufNet : IMyService
{
    public async Task<MyType?> GetEntityAsync(LongDTO paramLongRequest)
    {
        //if the entity doesn't exists in the database, the repository returns null.
        return await _repository.GetEntityById(paramLongRequest.Long);
    }
}



public class MyCLientProtobufNet
{
    public async Task<MyType?> GetEntityAsync(long paramId)
    {
        LongDTO miRequest = new LongDTO(paramId);

        return await _cliente.GetEntityAsync(miRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is non-specific and lacks any form of code. It may be closed by the community.  Protobuf doesn't permit nil Messages and, since `rpc` requires both a request and response message, it's not possible to send nil Messages. The server should return the default (not nil) response message and the client should expect such a message. Please consider adding the protobuf and|or client|server code that highlights the issue.

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227924/handling-null-values-in-protobuffers) seems to have useful advice that might help you

Comment: @DazWilkin I have added the code of the service and the client.

Comment: What does your *proto* file look like? It seems like the real question is whether you can have `optional` fields, which is indeed supported

Comment: `a method in the repository which may return a null value if the entity does not exist.` do you mean that the *gRPC* service is trying to return a null instead of an actual response? gRCP has an `Empty` message that can be used as a `don't care` response. In your case though a better response would be a message with an optional field. You *do* care about the response, and `Empty` or `null` is too vague.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I define a grpc call with a null request or response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768665/can-i-define-a-grpc-call-with-a-null-request-or-response)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, the answer that you suggest it is "pure" grpc. But protobuf-net allows to use CLR classes instead to use the proto contract. I know grpc (proto contract) doesn't accept null and has an Empty variable for that, but I was wondering if protobuf-net, how it allows CLR classes, it could allow a null response.

Comment: It's the other way around. Protobuf is the serialization protocol, not the contract or service protocol. It doesn't describe responses and messages. If you have *services*, it means you're using gRPC, or doing something really weird, like using protobuf as the serialization format for WCF or Web API. Which would be really weird.

Comment: And Protobuf.net is used to implement the services and messages defined in `proto` files, not the other way around. Just as WCF is used to implement WSDL and XSDs, not the other way around. You can start from the code instead of the `proto` or `wsdl` files and generate them, but in the end it's the schemas that define the service